# Why is the CALL instruction adding to the stack pointer?

Tags: assembly, bochs

For some reason when I run this code in bochs the value of BX at the start of the PRINTCHAR procedure resolves to 0x1002. How can this be? Doesn't the CALL procedure decrement SP and push the IP onto it, why has 2 been added to SP instead of subtracted? The register dump follows after the code listings. Thank you for reading.

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]
START:
MOV     AX,     0x0FA0
MOV     SS,     AX  
MOV     AX,     0x1000
MOV     SP,     AX
MOV     BP,     AX
MOV     AX,     0x1F40
MOV     DS,     AX
MOV     AX,     0x2EE0
MOV     ES,     AX
STI
CALL PRINTCHAR
CLI
HLT
PRINTCHAR:
MOV     BX,     SP
HLT
```

*Register Dump*

```
00014725614i[CPU0  ] WARNING: HLT instruction with IF=0!
04272480000p[WINGUI] >>PANIC<< POWER button turned off.
04272480000i[CPU0  ] CPU is in real mode (halted)
04272480000i[CPU0  ] CS.mode = 16 bit
04272480000i[CPU0  ] SS.mode = 16 bit
04272480000i[CPU0  ] EFER   = 0x00000000
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | EAX=00000e00  EBX=00001002  ECX=00090000  EDX=00000000
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | ESP=00001000  EBP=00001000  ESI=000e0000  EDI=0000ffac
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm rf nt of df if tf sf zf af pf cf
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  CS:0000( 0004| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  DS:1f40( 0005| 0|  0) 0001f400 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  SS:0fa0( 0005| 0|  0) 0000fa00 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  ES:2ee0( 0005| 0|  0) 0002ee00 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  FS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] |  GS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | EIP=00007c1c (00007c1c)
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | CR0=0x60000010 CR2=0x00000000
04272480000i[CPU0  ] | CR3=0x00000000 CR4=0x00000000
04272480000i[CPU0  ] 0x0000000000007c1c>> mov bx, sp : 89E3
```

Comment: For starters, your `PRINTCHAR` ends with a `HLT` instead of a `RET`.

Comment: @Jester yeah i am trying to capture the core dump just after the procedure is CALL'ed

Comment: Then you should put a `CLI` otherwise the cpu will continue past the `HLT` at the next interrupt and no telling what other code gets executed. Anyway, the simple thing would be to put a breakpoint and use the built in debugger instead. Note that `BX` saves the value properly so if you use a `RET` you can examine that at the first `HLT` which will indeed correctly show `0xffe`.

Comment: @Jester oh yeah you're right, after the RET BX holds the right value, so weird.

Comment: Note that the dump says "HLT with IF=0" so it actually can't be stopped at the HLT that comes after `mov bx, sp`, since you would have interrupts enabled at that point.  And if you were, EIP would point either to the HLT instruction itself, or perhaps the instruction after (depending how your emulator works), not the instruction before it.

Comment: So I am wondering if somehow you actually stopped at the *other* HLT instruction, #1 in source order, and have EIP pointing to the instruction after it which is `mov bx, sp`.  How you would have got there is unclear, but maybe your code previously executed the `mov bx, sp` and HLT #2, and then continued on after an interrupt occurred.  Maybe there is other code after what you showed us, or garbage in memory that got executed, that eventually took you to HLT #1, and changed the stack along the way?

Comment: Bochs's built-in debugger will let you single-step and watch register values change.  Seems to me that would be easier than messing around with `hlt`.

Comment: Since this is under Windows that you are running you may wish to run `bochsdbg.exe` which is another version of the BOCHS environment with the built in debugger. When it starts you can set a breakpoint at 0x7c00 with `b 0x7c00` do `c` to continue and then use `s` to step into (useful for stepping into functions or interrupts) or `n` next. I have tried to reproduce what you are seeing here with BOCHS 2.7 on Windows and haven't managed to reproduce this. Are you sure you were running the code you thought you were? Was there more code than this (note: you don't have a 0xaa55 at end of sector)

Answer (score 1):

Ms Debug shows good values ;) Maybe something is wrong with Bochs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bytes in RAM are never "empty" (but they contain some value) and most values are interpreted by the CPU as instructions.

For this reason, the memory after the end of a program contains "random" instructions.

Example: If you write the following program:

```
mov ax, 1
mov bx, 2
```

... then the memory may contain the following instructions:

```
# Instructions of your program
mov ax, 1
mov bx, 2
# Random instructions after your program
xor dx, ax
mov di, si
add dx, [di]
...
```

And if your program does not "end" propperly (e.g. you don't have an instruction that stops your program when it reaches the end), the CPU will execute those "random" instructions.

In the output of Bochs you can also see that the `ax` register has been modified (from 0x2EE0 to 0xE00).

The most probable reason for this is that the random instructions after your code caused the register changes - maybe these instructions look like this:

```
# Last part of your program
PRINTCHAR:
MOV     BX,     SP
HLT

# Random instructions after your program
MOV     BX,     0x1002
MOV     AX,     0xE00
RET
```